Get row changed and update cell in column D
I am trying to use OfficeJS in Excel Online to add a timestamp when a row is changed (specifically column A) to Column D on the same row.
I've been trying to modify the Scripts Lab example, below, but can't seem to figure out what is needed to get the row that was changed, then update column D in the row (although I think what I need to put in column D is "new Date(Date.now())".
$("#setup").on("click", () => tryCatch(setup));
$("#register-data-changed-handler").on("click", () => tryCatch(registerDataChangedHandler));

async function registerDataChangedHandler() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    const salesTable = sheet.tables.getItem("SalesTable");
    const salesByQuarterBinding = context.workbook.bindings.add(salesTable.getRange(), "Table", "SalesByQuarter");
    salesByQuarterBinding.onDataChanged.add(onSalesDataChanged);

    console.log("The data changed handler is registered.");

    await context.sync();
  });
}

async function onSalesDataChanged(eventArgs: Excel.BindingDataChangedEventArgs) {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    console.log("Data was changed with binding " + eventArgs.binding.id);

    // Get the name of the table that's changed.
    const table: Excel.Table = context.workbook.bindings.getItem(eventArgs.binding.id).getTable();
    table.load("name");

    await context.sync();

    console.log("Name of the changed table: " + table.name);
  });
}

Do I need to try something more like: this?
Update:  This works (in Office Scripts) but is super slow and still has to be run manually, so is not real-time:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const signinTableName = "signinTable" //replace for your signin table name
  const dateTableName = "dateTable"

  const signinTable = workbook.getTable('signinTable')//.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal()
  const dateTable = workbook.getTable('dateTable')

  for (let i = 0; i < signinTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues().length; i++) {

    if (signinTable.getColumnByName('Badge Number').getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRow(i).getValue() != "") {
      const dateTime = new Date();

      if (dateTable.getColumnByName('Sign-in Time').getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRow(i).getValue() === "") {
        
        dateTable.getColumnByName('Sign-in Time').getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRow(i).setValue(new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString())

      }
    }
  }
}


You’re combining technologies here. Are you wanting Office Scripts or OfficeJS (add-ins)? They’re not the same thing. The code you’ve supplied is OfficeJS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/add-ins-differences. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71935936/office-scripts-vs-script-lab

@Skin Thanks for your response!  I'm happy to use either one, if it'll will allow the task to be completed.  I'd use the simple formula =IF(A1<>"",IF(B1<>"",B1,NOW()),"") but that updates every time ANY cell is edited.  I'd also go the VB macro route, but that's not available in Excel Online (for the best).  I'd also use a Power Automate flow, but from our experience is that is not responsive enough.

Also, I believe it'll need to be OfficeJS, as Excel does not currently have an onChanged functionality at the column/table level.  The best code example I was able to find was the OfficeJS one I posted.
